# Approach to targetting HTTP Handler from Button Click

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

Main purpose here is to target the handler to download a file that is being previewed.

There are two different conditions of the file, one where it is already saved in the database, then the following parameters to the handler through a query string

COIHandler.axd?Action=preview_saved&letterId=xxxx

or

one that hasn't been saved yet, in which i store it in the session and target the handler in the following way

COIHandler.axd?Action=preview_unsaved

then the handler will handle clearing the session after I'm done.
Any thoughts on how to make this occur. Still new to http handlers.

**CLARIFICATION**

I have a OnClientClick property in my sub classed version of the Button class which allows me to append javascript to it that will be executed client-side. That is where I want the targeting to occur.

I want the user stay on the same page when they click the download button as well.

I dont want to simply do a redirect in javascript that will target the handler and I would like to avoid a pop-up window if possible. Not really sure if that leaves any options

Comment: What about using Button.PostBackURL instead of my custom javascript property? Just point it to the Handler and it shouldn't redirect or anything, just serve the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off thank you very much for all the possible solutions they were helpful in getting outside the box.

I figured out a unique solution that I thought I would share.

1. I place an invisible iframe in the html markup of my page.
2. then I set a property called OnClientClick in my server control Download Button (this allows me to render a parameter string to the onclick attribute of the html)

   I set the property to a javascript method which embodies a recursive algorithm to navigate to the top parent frame of the page, once it reaches that point, I use a simply JQuery selector to look for the iframe I spoke of in step 1. (The reason for the recursion is to maintain support with Master Pages where you will have frames inside of frames).
3. Set the src attribute of the iframe to the target HTTP Handler. The applied behavior causes the iframe to load the requested source ... but in this case it is a handler, and since it was made all originally from direct user input (via the Download button click), you won't even have the issue of getting the Yellow Bar with IE7+
4. The handler serves the request and the file is served to the browser

Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Your handler would actually be .ashx. Other than that your approach seems fine. You can examine the context that is passed into the PrcoessRequest method.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    switch(context.Request.QueryString["Action"].ToLower())
    {
       case "preview_saved":
           //do stuff for saved
       case "preview_unsaved":
           //do stuff for unsaved
     }
}
```

**UPDATE** If you want a central handler, then you'll either want to redirect the user at the end of the call in which case you'll also want to pass a `returnUrl` parameter in the query string. Then you can just do a `context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.QueryString["returnUrl"])`. Or if you want the page to retain its state, you're going to have to make an Ajax call to your handler.

Comment: I wrote a warpper for handling the Context but more or less that is the approach I am taking. I am going to clarify the question because it just occurred to me that its not quite clear enough.

Comment: @Matthew, then why not just have your Page handle this in a server click handler. Why do you need a different handler for this?

Comment: Good question. Requires more context =D  The reason is that the file being served is a pdf that is constructed from html strings. There are multiple different locations from within the product that utilize this feature, not just this one page. So I made a handler that serves the pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

In Response to Yads comment, you can use a button click handler on your page to download the file without a need for a popup or separate HTTP Handler.

```
protected void btnDownload_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{       
    PDFContentData data = GeneratePDFData(); //parses strings from some source (as mentioned in comments)
    WebFileUtil.InvokePDFDownload(Page.Context, data);
}

public static class WebFileUtil
{
    public static void InvokePDFDownload(HttpContext context, PDFContentData data)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();

        FileStore.generateDocument(data, context.Response.OutputStream);

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}_Documenth.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()));
        context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems may not have seen my response to that comment. This is not a good approach in my situation because this feature of serving pdf files occurs many different pages other than the one in question. So this approach would result in a copy paste solution.

Comment: @Mathew Cox - Ah, yes I did not see your comment in time. You could create a common web utility class for doing this and still have that reuse however. See my above code change.